# R extract only power from power.t.test

Tags: r

I am trying to use the curve() method to plot power as a function of delta. The only way I can figure out how to find power from a one sample t-test is using the power.t.test() method. However, this method returns several values, but I am only interested in power. The following my current code for calculating power:

```html
n1 = 5
SD = 0.10
power1 = function(x) power.t.test(n=n1, delta = x, sd = SD, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL, type = "one.sample")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str` to see the contents of what is returned. The power is element `power`, so your code should be

```
n1 = 5
SD = 0.10
power1 = function(x) power.t.test(n=n1, delta = x, sd = SD, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL, type = "one.sample")$power
```

and the power curve would be (for example)

```
curve(power1, .1, .8, xlab="SMD", ylab="Power")
```