# II type error in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have two samples of normal distribution. I have null hypothesis E=a1 and alternative E=a2

```
s1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = a1, sd = std)
s2 <- rnorm(1000, mean = a2, sd = std)
```

I can calculate I type error by doing this:

```
p_value = t.test(s1,alternative=c("t"),mu=a1)$p.value
if(p_value <= alpha) 
#then it's first type error
```

How can I calculate II type error?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Are you trying to calculate the theoretical type II error rate given the two samples means and standard deviations? Because that would have nothing to do with any particular set of samples.

Comment: Also, `if p_value <= alpha` does not imply a type I error

Comment: Sure, it's not a theoretical type. It's kind of estimation. I do these actions in cycle from 1 to 1000. I check the condition in every step and if so I increment num <- num + 1. 
At the end I get the result num/1000. This is my estimation for I type error. And I need the same kind for II type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of Type II error = 1- power

The power of a test:
[R extract only power from power.t.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966950/r-extract-only-power-from-power-t-test)

sig.level is the Type I error probability

If you want to understand the logic and why the p value alone wont give you the Type II error: 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-statistical-power-and-the-p-value

Comment: Thanks. I just don't understand if power.t.test returns a theoretical power or a power by sample. Don't you know?

Comment: Type 1 error, Type II error, power does not depend on the sample.

Comment: Type 1 error only depends on the probability distribution of the statistics T under the Null Hypothesis and the threshold alpha

Comment: Type 2 error only depends on the probability distribution of the statistics T under the Alternative Hypothesis and the threshold alpha

Comment: Dont hesitate to look for basic explanations for type I and type II error. They are difficult to understand at first I think! You could find very good examples and graphic to understand better on stack-overflow or equivalent platform. Bye =)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Bye :)